# Getting same information for standard result

Tags: sql-server

I have a query that should return this information:

```
Type  Quantity
C     54 
D     20
```

I have a type and the quantity of that type, sometimes I have data for C only, sometimes I have data for D only and sometimes I have both. I would like to be able to return always the two types and in case I don't have data, I'll show always both like this:

```
Type  Quantity
C     0
D     20
```

This result is based on a query that bring the information that exists on a table, so in case I don't have data for C, the result shows me only:

```
Type  Quantity
D     20
```

How can I fake data in a query using SQL Server 2008R2 in case one of those doesn't exists an bring always C and D?

Ok, this is the query:

```
SELECT STUFF(
    (           
        SELECT ',' + N'' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, [Type]) + ':' + CONVERT(NVARCHAR, COUNT([Quantity]))
        FROM #MyTable GROUP BY [Type]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
 ) ;
```

The result should bring something like that:

```
C:0, D:5
```

even if I don't have data for type C

Comment: Please post the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need a table with all the different `types` that you want (for my query I'll use a CTE). Then you can do:

```
;WITH CTE AS
(
    SELECT 'C' [Type]
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 'D'
)
SELECT STUFF(
    (           
        SELECT ',' + N'' + 
               CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), [Type]) + ':' + 
               CONVERT(NVARCHAR(20), ISNULL(COUNT([Quantity]),0))
        FROM CTE A
        LEFT JOIN #MyTable B
            ON A.[Type] = B.[Type]
        GROUP BY [Type]
        FOR XML PATH('')
    ), 1, 1, ''
 ) ;
```

As a note, you should always specify the length when defining or converting to `NVARCHAR`

Comment: yes, you are right, I forgot the length, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown your query to us, but I highly recommend looking into the exists() function; it may be what you are looking for.